# Replace hour items in array: "hh:mm" to "H"

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, datetime

I have an the following array:

```
hours = ["00:00", "04:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00"]
```

**Q:** How can I replace the items within the above `hours` array to:

```
newHours = ["0", "4", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22"]
```

Comment: Please paste any code you currently have. There is a lot of documentation around this, so perhaps try reading some (such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map with a regular expression.

```
var updated = hours.map( function (val) { return Number(val.match(/\d{2}/)[0]).toString()});
```

- `map()` - loops through the array
- `val.match(/\d{2}/)[0]` - matches the first two digits of the string
- `Number()` - will convert the string to number to get rid of leading zero - could have just done that with a reg exp.
- `.toString()` - convert it back to a string like you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parseInt()

```
var a = parseInt('00:00');
console.log(a); //returns 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do as bellow

```
hours.map(function(hour){
    var hourPart = hour.slice(0,2); //get the first two chars *hour part
    var asNumber = parseInt(hourPart); // convert hour part to number 
    return asNumber.toString(); // convert number to string and return
})
```

Prints

```
["0", "4", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using implicit casting and [`str.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) in [`arr.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var newHours = hours.map(function (e) {return '' + +e.slice(0,2);});
```